# Return same value for every instance of a method call

Tags: java, mockito

Hi I'm not using PowerMockito but normal one and trying to mock something like this:

```
when(any(File.class).canWrite()).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE)
```

But I get a `NullPointerException`. Basically without mocking a specific instance I want to mock any and all instances of a file object to return `FALSE` for `canWrite()`.

Can anyone help? I can mock the object but the code I'm testing is inside a static method.

Comment: What do you think `any(..)` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: I could use PowerMock I suppose but was wondering whether there was an way to return FALSE for all calls to canWrite() within the existing framework?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. With regular Mockito you need some mock object in the when() call, not an any matcher.

For your example, when you say any(File.class)

```
when(any(File.class).canWrite()).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE)
```

You need to have a file object already instantiated as a Mock

```
File fileMock = mock(File.class);    
when(fileMock.canWrite()).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE)
```

Comment: And he could also use a `spy`.

Comment: If he can get an instance of a file, yes. My understanding of the question though is that he wants every File that gets instantiated anywhere to be mocked. Even with a spy, with only regular Mockito, you could only do that if you can get an instance of the object.